# QSystemTrayIcon not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt, qsystemtrayicon

Using Kubuntu 18.04 (qt5 5.9.5), Python 3.6. I can't get this code to show the tray icon; other icons like Dropbox, etc. are shown, but this not:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon, qApp, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def run_something():
    print("Running something...")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Creating application...")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    print("Creating menu...")
    menu = QMenu()
    checkAction = menu.addAction("Check Now")
    checkAction.triggered.connect(run_something)
    quitAction = menu.addAction("Quit")
    quitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

    print("Creating icon...")
    icon = QIcon.fromTheme("system-help")

    print("Creating tray...")
    trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(icon, app)
    trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)

    print("Showing tray...")
    trayIcon.show()
    trayIcon.setToolTip("unko!")
    trayIcon.showMessage("hoge", "moge")

    print("Running application...")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The message ("hoge", "moge") is shown, but I can't find the icon anywhere... Neither in the left upper corner, as [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853511/pyqt5-qsystemtrayicon-is-outside-actual-tray) says.

Comment: `QIcon QIcon::fromTheme(const QString &name, const QIcon &fallback)` 
Returns the QIcon corresponding to name in the current icon theme. 
If no such icon is found in the current theme fallback is returned instead.
If you want to provide a guaranteed fallback for platforms that do not support theme icons, 
`you can use the second argument` : `icon = QIcon.fromTheme("system-help", QIcon('branch-end.png'))`

Comment: Thanks @S.Nick, also tried with a local icon without success.

Comment: Sorry, everything works in Windows 10.

Comment: Also tried with a clean installation of Kubuntu 18.10, same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea why, but this code works, sing PySide2 (basically is the same code than above...):

```
import logging
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QMenu, QApplication, QAction, QMessageBox


def run_something():
    print("Running something...")


def show_message():
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)

    msg.setWindowTitle("MessageBox demo")
    msg.setText("This is a message box")

    msg.setInformativeText("This is additional information")
    msg.setDetailedText("The details are as follows:")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    msg.exec_()


def show_tray_message(tray: QSystemTrayIcon):
    tray.showMessage("Hoooo", "Message from tray")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    tray = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("acorn.png"), app)
    menu = QMenu()

    action_test = QAction("Show a message box")
    action_test.triggered.connect(show_message)
    menu.addAction(action_test)

    action_tray_message = QAction("Show a message from tray")
    action_tray_message.triggered.connect(lambda: show_tray_message(tray))
    menu.addAction(action_tray_message)

    action_exit = QAction("Exit")
    action_exit.triggered.connect(app.exit)
    menu.addAction(action_exit)

    tray.setContextMenu(menu)
    tray.setToolTip("Tool tip")
    tray.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Also tested using `QIcon.fromTheme("system-help")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try PySide2.  I just got PySimpleGUIQt running with QSystemTrayIcon today on Linux and Windows with PySide2.  Maybe you'll have better luck there?